# Adding Events to Calendar without user confirmation

Tags: android, calendar

I'm trying to write a class to add events to a user's calendar in the background (not using intents). I need to ultimately be able to add as many as 7 events in a loop, so I can't do this with the approach where we turn control over to the calendar for the user to confirm.

Unfortunately, I'm not getting anywhere. The only feedback that I get from the logcat is a warning: `Cursor finalized without prior close()`

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
public class AddToCalendar {

    Context context;

    // Projection array. Creating indices for this array instead of doing
    // dynamic lookups improves performance.
    public static final String[] EVENT_PROJECTION = new String[] {
        Calendars._ID,                           // 0
        Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME,                  // 1
        Calendars.CALENDAR_DISPLAY_NAME,         // 2
        Calendars.OWNER_ACCOUNT                  // 3
    };

    // The indices for the projection array above.
    private static final int PROJECTION_ID_INDEX = 0;
    private static final int PROJECTION_ACCOUNT_NAME_INDEX = 1;
    private static final int PROJECTION_DISPLAY_NAME_INDEX = 2;
    private static final int PROJECTION_OWNER_ACCOUNT_INDEX = 3;

    public AddToCalendar (Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public Cursor getCalendars() {  
        Cursor cursor = null;
        ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
        Uri uri = Calendars.CONTENT_URI;   
        String selection = "((" + Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME + " = ?) AND (" 
                                + Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE + " = ?) AND ("
                                + Calendars.OWNER_ACCOUNT + " = ?))";
        String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {"sampleuser@gmail.com", "com.google",
                "sampleuser@gmail.com"}; 
        // Submit the query and get a Cursor object back. 
        cursor = cr.query(uri, EVENT_PROJECTION, selection, selectionArgs, null);

        return cursor;
    }

    public void addEvent(Cursor cursor, String type, String location, String description, Date workout_date) {

        System.err.println("adding event");

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

            String displayName = null;
            String accountName = null;
            String ownerName = null;

            // Get the field values
            long calID = 0;
            calID = cursor.getLong(PROJECTION_ID_INDEX);
            displayName = cursor.getString(PROJECTION_DISPLAY_NAME_INDEX);
            accountName = cursor.getString(PROJECTION_ACCOUNT_NAME_INDEX);
            ownerName = cursor.getString(PROJECTION_OWNER_ACCOUNT_INDEX);

            System.err.printf("Calendar: %s\n", displayName);

            long startMillis = 0; 
            long endMillis = 0;     
            Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
            beginTime.set(2014, 1, 26, 7, 30);
            startMillis = beginTime.getTimeInMillis();
            Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
            endTime.set(2014, 1, 26, 8, 45);
            endMillis = endTime.getTimeInMillis();

            ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(Events.DTSTART, startMillis);
            values.put(Events.DTEND, endMillis);
            values.put(Events.TITLE, type);
            values.put(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, location);
            values.put(Events.DESCRIPTION, description);
            values.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, calID);
            values.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, "America/Los_Angeles");

            cr.insert(Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
        }
    }
}
```

Most of this is pulled together from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html but it's just not working. Other than the warning that I mentioned, it all "appears" to work, except for the minor detail that nothing shows up on the calendar.

How do I write the getCalendars() query in a general way to get all of the calendars that might be on a user's device? Right now, you can see that I still have the language from the android site.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

EDIT: Andrew T pointed out that I have an off-by-one error since the months are zero-based, so I changed my hard coded date to be month 0. I also added a `cursor.close()` after my `while` loop. However, I still didn't have anything on my calendar.

One thing that I noticed was that I wasn't entering the `while` loop. So I took out the loop. When I hard-code the calID variable to 1, I finally get a calendar entry, but this concerns me. I thought that the point of getting the calendars was that a user might use multiple calendars on their device, and the cursor was a way of iterating over each of these calendars. Am I wrong about that?

If hardcoding calID to 1 will solve my problem, I'm fine with that, but I want to make sure that I understand this and am not relying on an ad hoc solution. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning is caused by not closing the Calendar `Cursor` after inserting the events. Call `cursor.close()` to close it.

Also, have you checked the events on February? I'm afraid you have off-by-1 issue with how month works in Java's `Calendar`. (Month starts with 0, which is `Calendar.JANUARY`)

**EDIT :**

It seems that there is a problem with `getCalendars()`, particularly on `String selection = ...` which returns empty `Cursor`. Also, with this approach, there is a possibility that the event will be added to multiple calendars, which might not be desired.

My idea is to create a `ListActivity` to list all calendars to let user chooses which calendar he wants to use. With this, you can also save the calendar ID to `SharedPreference` and use it when creating event conveniently.

I think you can use `cursor = cr.query(uri, EVENT_PROJECTION, null, null, null);` to list all calendars on the device.

Comment: Thank you. You're right on both counts. I didn't think to wonder if the months were zero based. I figured out how to get the event to appear on my calendar, but I don't trust that my approach is robust enough for all situations. I edited my OP to explain my change. What do you think about my edit? Thanks for your ideas. Very helpful.

Comment: Great suggestion about changing the query parameters. Using null for those two solved the problem. You're right that I need to come up with a way to allow the user to select from their list of calendars. Thanks for your help!